# adding one serializer fields to another -django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

my **serializer.py** file is as

```
...
class RelativeSerializerSLC(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    full_name = serializers.CharField(source="user.full_name")
    rtl_full_name = serializers.CharField(source="user.rtl_full_name")
    gender = serializers.CharField(source="user.gender")
    phone = serializers.CharField(source="user.phone")
    email = serializers.CharField(source="user.email")
    avatar = serializers.CharField(source="user.avatar")
    date_of_birth = serializers.CharField(source="user.date_of_birth")

    class Meta:
        model = Relative
        fields = ("full_name", "rtl_full_name", "gender", "phone", "email", "avatar", "date_of_birth", "blood_group", "rel")
        read_only_fields = ["patient"]


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "id", "full_name", "rtl_full_name", "gender", "phone", "email", "date_of_birth", "avatar"
```

there i'm creating other serializer fields(userSerializer) and added to my RelativeSerializer.
that seems uglyyy to me, i have no idea on. is there any better option like using one serializer fields for other.

Thanks, new to DRF :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
 class RelativeSerializerSLC(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   users = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
   class Meta: 
      model = Relative
      fields = ("full_name", "rtl_full_name", "gender", "phone", "email", "avatar", 
      "date_of_birth", "blood_group", "rel")
      read_only_fields = ["patient"]
```

And put UserSerializer class on top of the relativeSerializer. Let me know if it works. I don't see your model fields so it might not be.

Check out for nested serializers here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships